# How to create .env file in visual studio (sln) solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, .net-core

I working on one project need to create a .env file in my solution. When i click on add new item there is no .env file in that particular visual studio template.

Answer (score 1):

The file content for the .env file for Docker is just plain text. You can use the `Text File` template item from `Add>New Item>General` and name the file `foo.env`